# Pass generic type parameter class as argument

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums

Suppose I have a method

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> Enum<T> getEnumValue(String string, ??)
```

And another method, in a different class,

```
public T method(String string)
  ...
  getEnumValue(string, ??)
```

What would I pass from method 2 as the argument to method 1 so that I can get the enum value, i.e. in my fantasy world I could just do:

method 2:

```
getEnumValue(string, T.class)
```

method 1:

```
getEnumValue(String string, Class<T> clazz)
  return Enum.valueOf(clazz, string)
```

Comment: There is no way to do this due to type erasure.  _No way._  No way around having to pass the explicit `Class<T>`.

Comment: You could pass in your string information about full name of class/enum you want to use, and then value you want to get. Then parse this string to get name of type, use Class.forName and that is it. But that excludes generics since we are moving decision of selecting Class to runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this due to type erasure.  You *must* pass the explicit `Class<T>`, or enough information to recover it (e.g. the name as a `String` that you can pass to `Class.forName`, or an instance of `T`).

Comment: how do you get class name of type parameter object? Example: if function is
```
public <T extends Base> void convert(final T arg) {
}
```
How do i pass arg as Class<T> to other method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can call `arg.getClass()`, but that might be a subtype of T. There's no way to get the exact class T.  Or do you mean making the method `<T extends Base> convert(T arg, Class<T> clazz)`?

Answer (score -1):

`EnumClass.getEnumConstants()`

It's in `java.lang.Class` not `java.lang.Enum`. Use your `EnumClass.VALUE.cardinal()` to index this array.

If you insist to call on `String` name, you can do

`EnumClass.getEnumConstants()[0].valueOf(stringValue)`

This is to call static method on instance and you probably receive compiler warning but it works.